# Corrupted EditText backgrounds when using custom background drawables

Tags: java, android

I'm working on the android half of a cross-platform android/ios framework that lets you write apps in JS that work on both platforms. I say this because it means I can't use things like 9-patches to get this effect. Full code at https://github.com/mschulkind/cordova-true-native-android

Here are two screenshots of the problem:

-Images redacted because I'm too new to be this useful. I will have to add them when I'm no longer a newbie.-

Here's the code that generates the drawable from https://github.com/mschulkind/cordova-true-native-android/blob/master/src/org/apache/cordova/plugins/truenative/ViewPlugin.java#L146

```
  // Borrowed from:
  // http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/
  private class ViewBackground extends ShapeDrawable {
    private final Paint mFillPaint, mStrokePaint;
    private final int mBorderWidth;

    public ViewBackground(
        Shape s, int backgroundColor, int borderColor, int borderWidth) {
      super(s);

      mFillPaint = new Paint(this.getPaint());
      mFillPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);

      mStrokePaint = new Paint(mFillPaint);
      mStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      mStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
      mStrokePaint.setColor(borderColor);

      mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
      shape.resize(canvas.getClipBounds().right, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom);

      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.setRectToRect(
          new RectF(
            0, 0, 
            canvas.getClipBounds().right, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom),
          new RectF(
            mBorderWidth/2, mBorderWidth/2, 
            canvas.getClipBounds().right - mBorderWidth/2,
            canvas.getClipBounds().bottom - mBorderWidth/2),
          Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
      canvas.concat(matrix);

      shape.draw(canvas, mFillPaint);
      if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
        shape.draw(canvas, mStrokePaint);
      }
    }
  }
```

This has happened both when the drawable was set as the background of the EditText directly and when I set it as the background of a parent view around the EditText.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on here or what avenues I should explore?

Comment: Since I couldn't post them in the original post due to being a newbie, here are links to the screenshots 
http://i.imgur.com/ejHvJ.png and http://i.imgur.com/l1PNU.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to draw a rounded rectangle.

To achieve such a style, it is simpler to use a XML drawable.

You simply put a XML file into the drawable/ directory. Here you can describe the desired shape.
Some documentation about XML drawables is here : http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html
Look at the  tag.

Comment: I know about XML drawables, but it's not an option in this case. All parameters are specified directly in the javascript, so no chance to use XML; it has to be programmatically.